# looking for logical operator

Tags: matlab, binary, logical-operators

Here's a problem that is surprisingly hard for me to solve and I'm sure there must be an elegant solution: if any of the colums in the follow matrix `a_mat` contains exactly one logical `1`, output `1`, otherwise output `0`.

```
a_mat=[0 1 1 0; ...
       1 0 1 0; ...
       0 1 0 0];
```

solution:

```
sol_mat=[1 0 0 0];
```

Is there an 'easy' way to solve this problem using binary operators including xor etc? I used `setxor()` for previous, similar problems, however cannot get it to work with only one input-argument.

Comment: Could you just sum along columns and then perform a comparison?

Comment: Yes, I just was wondering if this could be done remaining within binary vectors/operators - I'm guessing there are some performance benefits in that, I guess it's just an academic challenge

Comment: I don't think that there's a better way than `sum()==1`. There's unlikely to be a benefit of "remaining binary". Binary operators are `all` and `any` (equivalent to AND or OR all elements in a column), there's no `one_of`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using `sum`:

```
sol_mat = sum(a_mat, 1) == 1
```

It's working fast enough in matlab.

Comment: Or `sum(a_mat,1) == 1` to be on the safe side

Comment: @LuisMendo :D Isn't that a part of your profile message?

Comment: @rayryeng Heh. I had forgotten about that!